# Looking for instructions how to run Dapr QuickStart sample locally without Kubernetes

Tags: dapr

I am going through the following Dapr sample:

https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/master/tutorials/hello-kubernetes

The sample needs Kubernetes.

To my understanding, Dapr can run locally with no need for Kubernetes.

Is there any instructions explain how to run above Dapr example locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tutorial runs the the same application locally without kubernetes:
https://github.com/dapr/quickstarts/tree/master/tutorials/hello-world

And this one also runs the same application locally inside docker containers:
https://github.com/dapr/samples/tree/master/hello-docker-compose